# How To Extract "ga:adPlacementDomain" along with "ga:CPC" and "ga:adClicks"

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm running a test adwords campaign (with auto-tagging), and driving traffic to my website. But I'm not getting any data from Google Analytics when I combine the metrics "ga:CPC" and "ga:adClicks" with the dimension "ga:adPlacementDomain".

Which is very strange since I KNOW this data is accessible when I look it up via the GA user interface.
Case in point: https://www.screencast.com/t/sMu1nIUYXWqh

So what's happening wrong when I use the API?

I'm using query explorer for testing purposes.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. would love to have an answer !